# Divide results of two queries by the results of another select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use the query below to calculate the difference between the lowest positive number in a table and the lowest negative value:

```
SELECT
(
  (
    SELECT SUM(ID) 
    FROM TABLE 
    where ID in 
    (
      select top 1 ID 
      from TABLE with (NOLOCK) 
      where ID > 0
    )
  ) - 
  (
    SELECT SUM(ID) 
    FROM TABLE 
    where ID in 
    (
      select top 1 ID 
      from TABLE with (NOLOCK) 
      where ID < 0 
      order by ID desc
    )
  )     
) As IDs_Remaining
```

How do I then take `IDs_Remaining` and divide by the results of another select query?

Comment: Are you aware of what that NOLOCK is really doing? Are you with missing and/or duplicate rows in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your difference query like this.

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 ID
        FROM   TABLE 
        WHERE  ID > 0 order by ID) - (SELECT TOP 1 ID
                          FROM   TABLE 
                          WHERE  ID < 0
                          ORDER  BY ID DESC)
```

then to divide by another query use this.

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 ID
        FROM   TABLE 
        WHERE  ID > 0 order by ID) - (SELECT TOP 1 ID
                          FROM   TABLE 
                          WHERE  ID < 0
                          ORDER  BY ID DESC) /--divider select query   as Result
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly. I was trying to declare variables and use UNION , I was way off the trail. Saved me a lot of time thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply divide with whatever other query you need:

```
SELECT
    (
        (SELECT ... ) - (SELECT ... )
    ) /
    (SELECT ... ) As FinalResult
```

Note that if ID is an integer, your division will also be an integer division (no fractions). So you might need to cast the denominator into a floating-point data-type before dividing by doing something like `CAST((SELECT ...) AS real)`

By the way, selecting the TOP 1 record from a table, does not ensure you get the one with the lowest value. So make sure to add `ORDER BY ID` or `ORDER BY ID ASC` also when you need the lowest value (this is true, even if ID is a Primary Key - order is never guaranteed, unless you explicitly type `ORDER BY`).

Also, it doesn't make sense to take the SUM of the ID column, if your ID column only contains distinct values. In that case, you could simply replace the first part of your query with:

```
SELECT (
    (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM TABLE WHERE ID > 0) -
    (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE WHERE ID < 0)
 ) as IDs_Remaining
```

Or, alternatively, to scan the table only once:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN ID ELSE NULL END) - 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID < 0 THEN ID ELSE NULL END) as IDs_Remaining
FROM TABLE
```